# How to get value from indicator in tradingview using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scripting, cryptography, binance

greeting everyone.
I am using a popular indicator in tradingview called `CM_Ult_MacD_MTF by ChrisMoody` where its combination many indicators and blinks `red` or `green` dot on the graph to tell when its good to long or short.
I want to somehow **scrape** or get that blink in python and don't know how to achieve that.

[image]

Here in the image where i circled the blinking dots.

My idea is to create a script where somehow i can **scrape** or get exact information as this one to give me notification (using telegram bot) but i don't know how to get that if you can give me idea or something.
Also source code of the indicator is available but it's written in pine script.

I had idea where i can get chart data and somehow create exact same of this indicator in python ("Not visual just numbers") but its really looking complicated and probably i will find not exact results as this one.
So what can i do, screenshot every minute and train a AI [Looks really hard work.]
Somehow get value by request.get the page (don't know how)
So I am open and thanks a lot.

Comment: did you get any progress on this? I'm trying to do something similar I have all the data and the indicator(a mall icon) is in tradingview but the issue is the pinescript is not public

Comment: Sorry to inform that, I no longer work on this because market is very volatile and it shows wrong results on my calculations and when there is huge drop or huge spike all the math changes and I am talking about crypto, if you are working on stocks and more stable pairs its possible to do so. Sorry not working anymore :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying the same but for a different indicator. If it is possible to you I would look into the pine script of the indicator and try to figure out, how it works. At least that's what I'm doing. In Python you can then use TA-Lib or Tulipy Library to replicate the results. For data gathering use your brokers' API and save it to a ".csv".
Good luck buddy.

Comment: I looked into the indicator and when you are only looking for the "dots" I would recommend looking for "cross" in the pine script (because that is what it is called in the indicators settings).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).